# Divide array in chunks with different sizes

Tags: arrays, swift, chunks, stride

I'm getting an array of data from HTML Scraping similar to this:

```
var resultArray = ["Maths", 2, 7, 8, "Grammar", 1, "Science", 7, 8]
```

What I want to do is do divide it when it finds a "String" value.
The result should look like this:

```
var new_arr1 = ["Maths", 2, 7, 8]
var new_arr2 = ["Grammar", 1]
var new_arr2 = ["Science", 7, 8]
```

The problem is that if I use something like this:

```
func chunk(_ chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
    return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map({ (startIndex) -> [Element] in
        let endIndex = (startIndex.advanced(by: chunkSize) > self.count) ? self.count-startIndex : chunkSize
        return Array(self[startIndex..<startIndex.advanced(by: endIndex)])
    })
}
```

I can only have a fixed "newArray" size.

Using Xcode8 and Swift3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `resultArray`? And why did you allow yourself to end up with something like this in the first place? You should have formed the end result _while you were scraping_.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know HTML a lot and I need to scrape a HTML Table by row, but there are not examples in Swift.

Comment: "the problem is that I don't know HTML a lot and I need to scrape a HTML Table by row, but there are not examples in Swift" There is not an "example" of everything you will ever want to do. Your job is to learn what you need to know and then do some _programming_. If you write your scraping code correctly, you shouldn't need to divide anything later.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out

Answer (score 2):

I think your entire spec is silly. You certainly cannot end up with a series of variables, as you propose. And to end up with yet another mixed array of string and numbers is completely counterproductive. You should rethink your goals (and if possible, you should rewrite your scraping code so as not to end up with a mixed array in the first place).

Anyway, given the input, here's how to end up with an array of tuples:

```
let resultArray : [Any] = ["Maths", 2, 7, 8, "Grammar", 1, "Science", 7, 8]
let nums = resultArray.split{$0 is String}
let strings = resultArray.filter{$0 is String}
let result = Array(zip(strings, nums)).map{($0, Array($1))}
print(result) // [("Maths", [2, 7, 8]), ("Grammar", [1]), ("Science", [7, 8])]
```

Comment: It's possible to be more efficient, esp. in Swift 4, but at least my approach here is straightforward and clear.